# trampoline function crashes

Tags: c, assembly, hook

I wrote a simple Hook function using some examples I saw here, and it works. 
I managed to redirect CreateProcess to a trampoline function that modified some parameters, than gave control back to CreateProcess.

I didn't like it because I used pop and push in order to do this when I could simply refer to their address relative to the ebp.

```
__declspec(naked)
InterceptCreateProc()
{
    LPBYTE pJmpAdr;

    void *inject;

    HMODULE hModule;
    void* oldFuncAdr;
    DWORD dwInject;

    inject = (void* )Inject; // function that will inject this dll in every process created
    dwInject = (DWORD)inject;

    __asm
    {
        // stack frame
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE // crashes with and without this

        or [ebp + 28], CREATE_SUSPENDED // dwCreationFlags | CREATE_SUSPENDED

        xor eax, eax
        mov eax, [ebp + 4] // return address
        mov g_returnAdrCreateProc, eax // save it

        mov eax, dwInject
        mov [ebp + 4], eax // new return address is my Inject function

        mov eax, [ebp + 44]
        mov g_procInfo, eax // lpProcessInformation
    };


    // give control back to CreateProcess
    hModule = LoadLibrary(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
    oldFuncAdr = (void* )GetProcAddress(hModule,
        "CreateProcessW");

    pJmpAdr = (LPBYTE)oldFuncAdr + 5;

    __asm
    {
        jmp pJmpAdr
        /*
          tried push pJmpAdr
                ret
          no difference
        */
    };
}
```

This crashes right before the last __asm block.

I can't figure out where I messed things up. 
Is it possible that the stack is somehow protected and when CreateProcess starts it sees that someone has written data there and crashes the application?

It didn't seem to mind when I did a lot of poping and pushing. 
Here is the old function which I thought had a higher chance to mess up the stack.

```
__declspec(naked)
InterceptCreateProc()
{
    LPBYTE pJmpAdr;

    LPCTSTR lpApplicationName;
    LPTSTR lpCommandLine;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes;
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes;
    BOOL bInheritHandles;
    DWORD dwCreationFlags;
    LPVOID lpEnvironment;
    LPCTSTR lpCurrentDirectory;
    LPSTARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo;
    LPPROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation;
    DWORD retv;

    void *inject;

    HMODULE hModule;
    void* oldFuncAdr;

    inject = (void* )Inject;

    __asm
    {
        pop retv
        pop lpApplicationName
        pop lpCommandLine
        pop lpProcessAttributes
        pop lpThreadAttributes
        pop bInheritHandles
        pop dwCreationFlags
        pop lpEnvironment
        pop lpCurrentDirectory
        pop lpStartupInfo
        pop lpProcessInformation
    };

    dwCreationFlags = dwCreationFlags | CREATE_SUSPENDED;
    g_returnAdrCreateProc = retv;
    retv = (DWORD)inject;
    g_procInfo = lpProcessInformation;

    __asm
    {
        push lpProcessInformation
        push lpStartupInfo
        push lpCurrentDirectory
        push lpEnvironment
        push dwCreationFlags
        push bInheritHandles
        push lpThreadAttributes
        push lpProcessAttributes
        push lpCommandLine
        push lpApplicationName
        push retv
    };


    __asm
    {
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
    };

    hModule = LoadLibrary(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
    oldFuncAdr = (void* )GetProcAddress(hModule,
        "CreateProcessW");

    pJmpAdr = (LPBYTE)oldFuncAdr + 5;

    __asm
    {
        jmp pJmpAdr
    };
}
```

I tried to figure out what I modified when I went to accessing directly the stack instead of pop-ing and push-ing, but I can't find anything.

Comment: `_declspec(naked)` means the prolog and epilog code is omitted, but you are not setting up the stack properly: you are not reserving any space for the stack variables.

Comment: It never told me that "the value of ESP was not properly saved" so I assumed things were ok. After the stack frame I added sub esp, __LOCAL_SIZE, but the app still crashes.

Comment: Could you look at the generated assembly? You're doing `inject = (void* )Inject;` before you've set up a stack frame, so I can't imagine that going well. Also, that warning can only be present in your own code, and not in `naked` functions.

Comment: That makes sense. With this being a trampoline should I also have a stack frame for what I do inside it and then destroy that frame before giving control back to CreateProcess? Also, this warning " warning C4054: 'type cast' : from function pointer 'void (__cdecl *)()' to data pointer 'void *'" Why is Inject seen as __cdecl when it is naked?